# COPY does not add my file to Docker container

Tags: docker

I'm trying to add a private key `docker-upload` to a docker container:

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum -y -q install openssh-clients && \
  yum clean all && \
  rm -rf /var/cache/yum

RUN \
  mkdir -p ~/.ssh && \
  touch ~/.ssh/known_hosts && \
  ssh-keyscan -p 2022 -t rsa hostname > ~/.ssh/known_hosts

COPY docker-upload ~/.ssh/

RUN ls -all ~/.ssh
```

When building with

`docker build --no-cache -t privateregistry.com/build-containers:upload .`

I get that the ~/.ssh directory is empty:

```
Step 5/7 : COPY docker-nerds-upload ~/.ssh/
 ---> 2bafa09dd03c
Step 6/7 : RUN ls -all ~/.ssh
 ---> Running in 1c74fc1d0e14
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 18 14:19 .
dr-xr-x--- 3 root root 4096 Apr 18 14:19 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Apr 18 14:19 known_hosts
```

Why doesn't `COPY docker-upload ~/.ssh/` copy the file `docker-upload` into the `~/.ssh` directory in the docker container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The `dest` is an absolute path, or a path relative to WORKDIR, into
>   which the source will be copied inside the destination container.
>
> [Reference(Dockerfile COPY)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)

Tilde(`~`) expansion for COPY is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow `COPY` doesn't like `~` as path. With absolute paths it works

```
COPY docker-upload /root/.ssh
```